# Adding more documents to existing collection in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

Assume I have an eCommerce App where USERS can sell their items. This is how my DB structure looks like:

[image]

Now lets see, if I want that one user to sell several items at a time. Hence in DB all his items are listed under the same document with his name "USER-01". (Like this in DB)

[image]

So in short, what I am asking for is: Is it possible to store a LIST of maps in a document instead of just one?
Or how else do you suggest should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to store a list of maps.  Simply provide an array containing the maps objects you want to store.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("your-collection").add({
    "a-list-field": [
        {"key1": 1, "key2": "a"},
        {"key1": 2, "key2": "b"}
    ]
})
```

Keep in mind that Firestore documents are limited to 1MB in size, so if the list could get large, you should consider instead storing them in individual documents in a nested subcollection.  It's entirely up to you to decide what's best, based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately firebase doesnt support Lists. You could instead create an array of Maps which should give you the same functionality you're looking for.